How can a swap between two decentralized exchanges (DEXs) be made atomic?
Is it possible to write a program that buys a token on Raydium, then sells it on Orca, and if there’s an error during the sale on Orca, to reverse the changes and refund the user on Raydium? How can this be made atomic? I can’t find any information on this, as calls via CPI violate atomicity; what topics should I study?

Possible!
Here are the key topics and steps you should delve into:
Key topics you should delve into:

Solana Programming Model
Cross-Program Invocation (CPI)
Custom Solana Programs for State Management
Understanding DEX APIs and Integration
Atomic Transactions and Pessimistic States

Practical Implementation Steps:

Initial Purchase on Raydium:


Execute the token purchase transaction on Raydium.
Lock the purchased tokens in an intermediary account controlled by your custom program.


Attempt Sale on Orca:


Use a CPI to interact with the Orca program to sell the tokens.
Ensure you have error handling to catch failures in the sale process.


State Change and Conditional Rollback:


If the sale on Orca fails, trigger a rollback mechanism:
Reverse any interim state changes.
Refund tokens to the user by executing compensation transactions.
If the sale is successful, finalize the transaction.


Transaction Composition and Combination:


Develop a meta-transaction that combines these steps.
Test thoroughly to ensure any failure mode is handled gracefully.

Check below repositories:

https://github.com/raydium-io
https://github.com/orca-so


To begin with, many thanks to you for your help.
*Refund tokens to the user by executing compensation transactions.
Can you please tell me more about this? Will this happen without loss of funds? That is, in case of a rollback, we will fully refund our funds?



Lock user's funds in an intermediary account managed by your custom program to ensure safety.


Execute the token purchase on Raydium using CPI and hold purchased tokens in the intermediary wallet.


Use CPI to sell tokens on Orca. Implement error handling mechanisms to catch and manage failures.


If the sale on Orca fails:
Undo any state changes during the process.
Refund user's locked funds by rolling back the transaction.


If the sale on Orca succeeds, finalize by moving proceeds (minus any fees) to the user's account.


